# grabbing Parsley JS field error and updating CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsley.js

I'm completely new to ParsleyJS and don't really know if what I am doing is a wrong way to approach this. But, as I get an error on a particular field that is being validated by Parsley, **I want to update the CSS on the field to outline a solid red border**. I have the following code, where I can extract the CSS, but cant seem to attach a JQuery call to update the CSS on the field.

```
$('form#logon.parsleyParse').parsley().on('field:error', function() {
    console.log('Validation failed for: ', this.$element);
    var element = '#' + this.$element[0].id;
    console.log(element);
    $(this.$element[0].id).css("border: 1px solid red !important;");
});
```

Basically, when I console log that element, it prints out the proper CSS element.. But, I can seem to make the call to JQuery to change the CSS..

Any ideas on what the best way to do this? Or how to do this properly?

Comment: Why not...just use CSS? What is the reason to use JS for this task?

Comment: i only want the red outline on the field, if there is a validation error. is there something i am missing that parsley offers, as far as added classes to the field on validation errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsley will add error classes for you, so you simply need to specify some CSS rules for those classes.

Parsley has many examples, check out how it's done there.

Comment: im not the smartest guy in the room, but this made perfect sense for me, and i found it. "Parsley adds its share of classes and elements, to ease nice UI validation result display. By default, it will add **parsley-success** and **parsley-error** classes depending on the validation result, on the input itself for a simple text, textarea and select input, and on the parent for radio / checkboxes inputs."